# How to get and display value from Api in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, get, fromjson

I want to fetch and display the data from api. data is like card details name, number, email etc.. I want to get multiple cards based on phone number. for eg: if 2 cards linked to phone number. it will show both cards. for that i am using Future builder and list view builder. but I am getting Values in temp variable in getData function. please check get

```
List<DataDetails> multiCardData=[];

Future<List<DataDetails>> getData() async { 
 final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https.url'));


 var temp = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

 if(response.statusCode == 200) {

  String qrCodeData = 'BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0;\nN:${temp.name};\nORG:${temp.company}\nTITLE:${temp.designation}\nADR:${temp.address};;;;;;\nTEL;CELL:${temp.phone}\nEMAIL:${temp.email}\nEND:VCARD';
  temp.qrCode = qrCodeData;

  

  for(Map i in temp) {
      multiCardData.add(DataDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(i)));
  }

  return multiCardData;
} else {
  return multiCardData;
}
```

}

I am getting data in temp variable like temp have values [0,1,2] in 2 [key, values] in values[0,1]. 0 = card one data values and 1= card two data values both are linked to same mobile number but i am not able to display the data. I want to display cards and how many cards  linked with same moblile number in a List view. please guide

Thank you